# How to get babel-node to convert files referenced by Workers to commonjs? (like babel does)

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, babel-node

In an Express.js app, I'm using Babel to precompile to commonjs before starting it. The compilation step looks like this:

```
babel ./src --out-dir dist
node ./dist/bin
```

As part of the project I have a file called `my-worker.js` where I use `import syntax`:

```
# my-worker.js

import { parentPort, workerData } from 'worker_threads'
import axios from 'axios'
...
```

And that is used by `other-file.js`:

```
#other-file.js

...
const worker = new Worker(__dirname + '/my-worker.js', { workerData: ... })
...
```

**This works fine. Babel converts all the files to commonjs, and loading the worker script works**.

**BUT**

When I use `@babel/node`, this doesn't work:

```
babel-node ./src/bin
```

I get the warning:

> (node:4865) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.

Along with the error:

> Cannot use import statement outside a module

I don't want to use `"type": "module"`, since then I have to explicitly name file extensions, and also I'm not sure that `import X, { y } from ...` syntax is supported (which I like).

If I change my worker file to be `my-worker.mjs`, and change the `new Worker` statement accordingly, then that works with `@babel/node`, but not with my production build since filenames are changed back to `.js`.

How can I get `@babel/node` to load and cache (I guess this is what it needs to do?) files loaded by a Worker? Why does this work with `@babel` and not with `@babel/node`?

---

My `.babelrc` file looks like this:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "corejs": 3,
        "targets": {
          "node": "13"
        },
        "modules": "commonjs"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: The solution I am currently using is that I'm getting the name of the files that I want to run via `fs.readFileSync` on app startup. Then in dev I can use `.mjs`, which is fine for Node 13, and in production, the commonjs output is `.js`, and `fs.readFileSync` finds the `.js` files.

Comment: For a more babel oriented approach: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/10972

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@babel/register` API can help dynamically transpile a script source, as pointed out in https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/10972#issuecomment-572608142

You can use this approach with eval mode to make a single-file script. This might be useful if you use `babel-node` to run a command-line utility script.

```
import { isMainThread, Worker, workerData } from "worker_threads";

function createTranspiledWorker(filename, options) {
  const transpile = `
    require('@babel/register');
    require(${JSON.stringify(filename)});
  `;
  return new Worker(transpile, { ...options, eval: true });
}

async function main() {
  const w = createTranspiledWorker(__filename, { workerData: { hello: "world" } });
  const exit = new Promise(resolve => w.on("exit", resolve));
  await exit;
}

function worker() {
  console.log("worker", workerData);
}

if (isMainThread) {
  main();
} else {
  worker();
}
```